# How to structure wordpress category base, category pages and single post urls

Tags: wordpress, pagination, categories, permalinks

Please bear with me. This problem has been eating at me for years.

I have a website with three categories [news][media][others].

Wordpress Reading Settings front-page set to static page, post page set to created page with slug /news/

**Expectation**

- myjournal.com --> Front page
- myjournal/news/ --> created page with slug /news/ to show all 3 categories
- myjournal/news/news/ --> category page for news
- myjournal/news/news/festival-party/ --> single post url

**/////////////////////// SCENARIO I //////////////////////**

1. Permalinks Category base is set to /news/
2. Permalinks Custom Structure --> /%category%/%post_id%/
3. Yoast category base --> Keep

**Reality**

- myjournal/news/ --> broken pagination page 2 (page can't be found)
- myjournal/news/news/ --> works as intended. including pagination!
- myjournal/news/festival-party/ --> single post url does not include category base

**/////////////////////// SCENARIO II //////////////////////**

1. Permalinks Category base is set to blank
2. Permalinks Custom Structure --> /news/%category%/%post_id%/
3. Yoast category base --> Keep

**Reality**

- myjournal/news/  --> works perfectly. including pagination!
- myjournal/news/news --> broken pagination page 2 (page can't be found)
- myjournal/news/festival-party/ --> works as intended

**///// END**

Seems like a really normal site structure but i just can't get it to work.
Any advice would be great!